# read mutiple json files from multiple directories

Tags: python, json, directory

i have multiple directories which all contain JSON files.
I know how I could read all in ONE directory, but not how to read them in all directories without specifying the dirctory names.

I played around and came up with something like this:

```
import json
import os

path_to_json = 'path/to/dir/with/dirs' 
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json)]


for json_file in json_files:
    filename = str(json_file + "/") # here something like "*.json"
    with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.walk` with `str.endswith`

**Ex:**

```
path_to_json = 'path/to/dir/with/dirs' 
json_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_json):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.json'):      #Check for .json exten
            json_files.append(os.path.join(root, f))    #append full path to file
            
for json_file in json_files:
    with open(json_file, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os.walk` and give the top level directory as the directory_name.

```
import os

root = "<path-to-dir>"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.json'):
            with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
                data = myfile.read()
```